# Mensaje de Confirmación - Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Mi mensaje de confirmación para `Xamarin.Android` no funciona:

```
public async void MensajeAlertaSiNo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool answer = await DisplayAlert("¿Estas seguro?", "Recuerda que puedes editarlo en lugar de eliminarlo." 
                + System.Environment.NewLine + "¿Deseas eliminar definitivamente este post?", "Eliminar", "Cancelar");
            
        }
```

No me reconoce `DisplayAlert`.

Comment: await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inténtalo de esta forma:

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.SetTitle("¿Estas seguro?");
                builder.SetMessage("Recuerda que puedes editar el post en lugar de eliminarlo."
                + System.Environment.NewLine + "¿Deseas eliminar definitivamente este post?");
                builder.SetCancelable(true);
                builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancelar", delegate
                {
                    //No eliminar. Do nothing.
                });
                builder.SetPositiveButton("Eliminar", delegate 
                { 
                    EliminarPost(); 
                });
                builder.Show();
            }
             );
```